# Get distinct item in nested array using n1ql

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

I have a document structure like this

```
{
  "tags": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

I find the way how can I do it using map & reduce function.

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html

However, if I would like to use n1ql to perform the same query, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details, such as a sample document and a sample of the results you want? Also, note that N1QL works with Couchbase, not CouchDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [nested operators](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/nestedops.html) in N1QL.